# Mask view transition animation with React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

Coming from a native iOS background, I have recently started working with react native. A while ago, I have implemented a view transition like that with Swift :

[image]

Following this tutorial : 
[How To Make A View Controller Transition Animation Like in the Ping App](https://www.raywenderlich.com/86521/how-to-make-a-view-controller-transition-animation-like-in-the-ping-app)

I'm wondering if creating something similar with react native would be possible. If yes, how should I approach it? I just need a hint and some intuition on how to proceed with this idea.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?